# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte in 0xc3 in position 304: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, macos, syntax-error, python-unicode

I just left the PC at work (using Python 2.7) and had a script that I was just finishing up (reproduced below). It ran fine at work, I just wanted to add one or two things. But I came home and am using my Mac's version of Python (3.2.2) and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Downloads/sda/alias.py", line 25, in <module>
    for row_2 in in_csv:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 304: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My code is here:

```
import csv
inname = "Fund_Aliases.csv"
outname = "output.csv"

def first_word(value):
    return value.split(" ", 1)[0]

with open(inname, "r") as infile:
    with open(outname, "w") as out file:
      in_csv = csv.reader(infile)
      out_csv = csv.writer(outfile)

     column_names = next(in_csv)
     out_csv.writerow(column_names)

      id_index = column_names.index("id")
      name_index = column_names.index("name")

      try:
          row_1 = next(in_csv)
          written_row = False

          for row_2 in in_csv:
            if first_word(row_1[name_index]) == first_word(row_2[name_index]) and row_1[id_index] != row_2[id_index]:
                if not written_row:
                    out_csv.writerow(row_1)

                out_csv.writerow(row_2)
                written_row = True
            else:
                written_row = False

            row_1 = row_2
      except StopIteration:
        # No data rows!
        pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `Fund_Aliases.csv` is not an ascii file.

According to the [Python3 docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html#module-csv):

> Since open() is used to open a CSV file for reading, the file will by
>   default be decoded into unicode using the system default encoding (see
>   locale.getpreferredencoding()). To decode a file using a different
>   encoding, use the encoding argument of open:

```
with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
```

So try specifying the `encoding` parameter.

Comment: thanks! That did the trick, I just had to update the following two lines accordingly:                                                  with open(inname, "r", encoding = "utf-8") as infile:
    with open(outname, "w", encoding = "utf-8") as outfile:

Comment: Just to clarify, a CSV file on a PC is not the same ASCI format as that CSV file emailed and downloaded onto a Mac. Does this essentially mean that 1-2 lines of code in the Apple operating system makes this file different from that of the Windows operating system?

Comment: It could of course make a big difference depending on what is in those 1-2 lines of code. But in general, if there is a difference, it is usually limited to differences in EOL characters (`'\n'` for unix, versus `'\r\n'` for Windows), or differences in encoding. Being explicit about the encoding should help avoid that problem.

Comment: I sheepishly admit that I'm new to unicode. FYI I found these helpful: http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/unicode.html , http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html