# Python: from a text file to dictionary with keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, text-files

I have a text file with eight names, sorted by name, like this:

```
Anna
David
Dennis
Morgan
Lana
Peter
Joanna
Karen
```

And now I want to put them into a dictionary and add different keys to each of the name.
The names are on new lines. What I want to add to the names in the dict, are different binary numbers from 000-111. 
How can I do this?

I have tried stuff like this:

```
with open ('tennis.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:

dict={}
for line in open('file.txt'):
        bin[0]=next(f)
        bin[1]=next(f)
        bin[2]=next(f)
        bin[3]=next(f)
        bin[4]=next(f)
        bin[5]=next(f)
        bin[6]=next(f)
        bin[7]=next(f)
```

Comment: Are the names on new lines, or all on one line?

Comment: What do you mean by "add different keys"?

Comment: Can you provide an example? The question is not clear.

Comment: I added some more information now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [andybuckley's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91808/andybuckley) answer, you can get it done like this:

```
d = {}
f = open("tennis.txt")
for i, l in enumerate(f):
    # cut the '0b' chars, so you will get your dict keys just like you want
    bin_num = bin(i)[2:]
    # if the key is shorter than 3 chars, add 0 to the beginning
    while len(bin_num) < 3:
        bin_num = '0' + bin_num
    d[bin_num] = l[:-1]

f.close()
for i in sorted(d.items()):
    print i
```

**EDIT** : Thanks to @pepr - remember to close the opened file. 
Output:

```
('000', 'Anna')
('001', 'David')
('010', 'Dennis')
('011', 'Morgan')
('100', 'Lana')
('101', 'Peter')
('110', 'Joanna')
('111', 'Karen')
```

Comment: I get a TypeError, an integer is required.. Before that i added 'r' and 'utf8' after the file name, is that incorrect?

Comment: You don't have to do that. Just save the code I posted as a python file in the same folder as your tennis.txt file and run it. In what line do you get that error?

Comment: it says like this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/josefinilic/Documents/tennistest2.py", line 2, in <module>
    for i, l in enumerate(open("tennis.txt")):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I think that this thread should be helpful for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909905/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-in-0xc3-in-position-304-ord

Comment: You forgot to close the file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to know what you want: I've interpreted the question as wanting to read names from a text file, and to insert each into a dict with an increasing binary key. Here's an interactive Python3 session which does that and shows the populated dictionary:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for i, l in enumerate(open("tennis.txt")):
...     d[bin(i)] = l[:-1]
>>> d
{'0b10': 'Dennis', '0b11': 'Morgan', '0b110': 'Joanna', '0b0': 'Anna', '0b1': 'David', '0b101': 'Peter', '0b100': 'Lana', '0b111': 'Karen'}
```

Note that I've used "d" rather than "dict" as the name for the dictionary variable, since I don't want the variable name to hide the class name: it's always a good idea to avoid using the same names for variables and classes, although Python will not object.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict comprehension, zfill, and enumerate:

```
with open('/tmp/names.txt') as f:
    print({bin(k)[2:].zfill(3): v.strip() for k,v in enumerate(f)})
```

Prints:

```
{'000': 'Anna', '001': 'David', '011': 'Morgan', '010': 'Dennis', '101': 'Peter', '100': 'Lana', '110': 'Joanna', '111': 'Karen'}
```

If you don't know how many lines there are in the file in order to use the right number for `zfill`, you can just count them first:

```
with open(fn) as f:
    i=max(ln for ln,line in enumerate(f) if line.strip())
    print(i, bin(i)[2:])
    fill=len(bin(i)[2:])
    f.seek(0)
    print({bin(k)[2:].zfill(fill): v.strip() for k,v in enumerate(f) if v.strip()})
```